# Hyperlink button in the same slide that consists of "\includepdf"

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, positioning

I am making slide using beamer.
I'd like to use hyperlink button at the end of the table from another PDF file named `table4`.

I am trying the following, but "main" button shows up different slide.
Is there any way that table and hyperlink button are shown in the same slide?

```
{
        \label{within} 
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
    \includepdf[width=1.8\textwidth, height=2.5\textheight, pages=1]{table4.pdf}

    Back to \hyperlink{main}{\beamerbutton{main}}.
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `pagecommand= option` of `\includepdf`; to control the position of the button, you can use `\vspace*` and `\hspace`. A little example, in which the button is first stored in a macro and then the macro is used for `pagecommand`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcommand\mybutton{%
\vspace*{.5\textheight}\hspace*{.4\textwidth}Back to \hyperlink{main}{\beamerbutton{main}}%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test\hypertarget{main}{}
\end{frame}
{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
\includepdf[offset=0 -80,height=2\textheight, pages=1,pagecommand=\mybutton]{c.pdf}
}
\begin{frame}
A normal frame.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And the frame containing the included pdf file and the button (I modified the settings for my example, but you can do the adjustments that you consider necessary):

[image]

The file `c.pdf` I used in the example was the result of pdflatex-ing the following `c.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo. I got the hyperlink button, but now I have another problem. After using "pagecommand", beamer theme has changed to original warsaw. Before using this command, it was just plain theme from pdf file. I have no idea why it changed.

Comment: @justin: please see my updated answer.

Comment: @justin: since my answer apparently solves your problem, please consider "accepting" it by clicking on the tickmark below the vote count.